# Conversion Date in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I use this code in the ASP.net to search for a particular article within a certain period
Either choose the beginning of the period or the end of the period

I used

```
 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtBox1" PropertyName="Text" Name="StartDate">
         </ asp: ControlParameter>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtBox2" PropertyName="Text" Name="EndDate">
         </ asp: ControlParameter>
```

And I used this sql query

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT 
        AnnouncementID, 
        Title, 
        content, 
        PostedDate
FROM
        Announcement 
WHERE
        (Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%' OR @Title IS NULL)
AND
        (CONVERT(DATE, PostedDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate,103) AND CONVERT(DATE, @EndDate)
        OR
        (CONVERT(DATE, PostedDate) &gt;= CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate,103) AND @EndDate IS NULL)
        OR
        (CONVERT(DATE, PostedDate) &lt;= CONVERT(DATE, @EndDate,103) AND @StartDate IS NULL)
        OR
        (@StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL))" 

        CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False"
```

it's work and convert StartDate good
also EndDate but when I put date up to 12 in the EndDate
like 31/12/2011 
appear this error
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I don't know what cause this error while it's work in StartDate

Comment: Try to set [ControlParameter's Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.type%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to `"DateTime"`.

Comment: thank you I solved problem I forget put number of style in second row here (CONVERT(DATE, PostedDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate,103) AND CONVERT(DATE, @EndDate) <-- 103